# Python: Searching and Manipulating a 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, replace

I am back with another question about lists, but this time it's about 2D lists. I tried using the previous method given to me for changing the values in a list given in the code below. However, this doesn't work when i use a 2D list. here's the code:

```
    fruits = [ 
["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"],
["Apple", "Banana", "Watermelon", "Lemon"]
]
print(fruits)

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

for i in range(len(fruits)):
    if fruits[i] == findFruit:
        fruits[i] = replaceFruit


print(fruits)
```

Another question I have is using a function to count how many instances of a 'findFruit' there is in the list, I have tried using the count() in the 2D list and it hasn't worked too.

Comment: Can you print `fruits[i]` and see what it is?

Comment: It just prints the second list: ["Apple", "Banana", "Watermelon", "Lemon"]

Comment: So how can it be equal to `findFruit`? You need another iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D list would have rows and columns, say mXn, your list is 2X4, but you are only checking for the 2 rows.

```
fruits = [["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"], ["Apple", "Banana", "Watermelon", "Lemon"]]
print(fruits)

findFruit = input("Fruit: ")
replaceFruit = input("Replace: ")

for i in range(len(fruits)):    # len(fruits) is 2
    for j in range(len(fruits[i])):    # len(fruits[i]) is 4
        if fruits[i][j] == findFruit:
            fruits[i][j] = replaceFruit


print(fruits)
```

Comment: As for using count(), you can loop through each row, and sum the fruits[i].count(findFruit) values to get the total count in the 2D list

Answer (score 0):

Use count function for each of fruits[i]

You have to use nested for loop to access each element in 2D list.

As,
fruits[0] will be ["Banana", "Apple", "Watermelon", "Apple"]

and,
fruits[0][1] will be "Apple"

So use the loops properly.